# Why did Scientists still follow Newton's scientific framework, even though Kant debunked it?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, history-of-philosophy

Why did physicists still followed Newton's framework all the way until the early 20th century, Pre-Einstein

Kant wrote a book criticizing Newtonian mechanics (metaphysics) did many physicists simply not read Kant, or disregarded his takedown of Newton?

Comment: What exactly was debunked? Many engineering fields are still based on Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: @Cell Absolute space, a Newtonian idea that led to e.g. the theory of the Aether to be maintained, was refuted by Kant in his Metaphysical Foundations of Natural Sciences from 1784.

Comment: At first, it'd be better if you would be more specific. What book do you mean and maybe you should quote some main points. At second, modern science partially debunks Kant. Finite speed of light, for example.

Comment: Newton is still correct for the most part. At least to any order of magnitude you and I work to on a daily basis..

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking does "Newton's scientific framework" refer to absolute space? And is that still something that scientists follow?

Comment: @Cell Definitely not something that scientists follow. Relativism rejects absolute space.

Comment: @Richard Flat-earthers are correct to any order of magnitude we work to on a daily basis as well. Unless you are creating airplane/sail routes or work within space industry.

Comment: @rus9384 That is not a fair comparison. Newton's laws are directly used by engineers while believing the earth is flat is not something that is employed by any kind of calculation or work of any kind.

Comment: @Cell We know Noether's theorem does not apply to our universe, therefore third Newton's law does not hold. Second is refuted by relativity. Dunno about first, but it might have its limitations as well. When dividing small areas people assume the Earth is flat, they don't count curvature when measuring the area of private land.

Comment: @rus9384 You say Newton's third law does not hold and the second is refuted, yet all the buildings, bridges, and chemical plants designed by engineers on those very principles did not suddenly fall apart how odd.

Comment: @Cell: Engineers work with sufficiently precise numbers, i.e. sufficiently precise for what they want and need. This is something models that are factually incorrect can still provide. Almost *all* formulas successfully used in engineering are more or less "wrong", i.e. imprecise. Just ask any physicist about an engineer's maths and they will confirm that. Also, absolute space is factually wrong and the only Newtonian "framework" Kant refuted to my knowledge. He was actually quite fond of Newton.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking  so why did physicists still continue to work with Newtonian Mechanics after Kant's refutation of absolute space?

Comment: @user4281 Again, why don't architects take into account Earth's curvature? And they work with Newtonian mechanics because they provide precision enough for their purposes. Sometimes they need to take relativity into account, when precision is not enough.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Your logic does not make sense. If something empirically works, then it is by definition factual. Maybe you don't work in engineering or science. But just because a chemical formula or theorem is not universal or has exceptions it is not referred to by professionals as being "non-factual" and I think you are giving incorrect information in your answer. But my comments are no longer relevent here so this will be the last of me.

Comment: "Kant wrote a book criticizing Newtonian mechanics (metaphysics)--- " But the issue is that Newton's mechanics works, while metaphysics (either Newton's or Kant's one) does not.

Answer (score 5):

A compelling answer is given in Rynasiewicz, R. (1996). Absolute Versus Relational Space-Time: An Outmoded Debate? The Journal of Philosophy, 93(6), 279-306. doi:10.2307/2941076

> Isaac Newton provided the locus classicus for
>   substantivalism in the scholium to the opening definitions of the
>   *Principia*, where he laid out and defended the distinction between
>   absolute space and time and their relative counterparts. The major natural philosophers on the Continent, most notably Christian Huygens
>   and G. W. Leibniz, as well as such fringe figures for the new science
>   as Bishop Berkeley, voiced vehement objections, but failed to
>   offer any real alternative in the way of a dynamics founded on relationist
>   principles. Nor did any other classical relationist, including
>   Ernst Mach, succeed in this regard. (pp. 279-280)

Hence, although there were very good *metaphysical* reasons to refute absolute space, the mathematical tools of the time offered no means for a working alternative in relative frames so that the formulas could account for dynamic systems as Newton with his absolute space could. The same applies to Kant, who obviously was not the first (and not the last) one to refute this particular aspect of Newtonian physics.

In other words: Even though the philosophical insight was old in Kant's time already, Newtonian physics were the only ones offering formulas with predictive value for all aspects of mechanics known at the time. Obviously, even with a wrong premise, the conclusions still worked in non-relativistic environments (because of low velocity and/or low curvature of space), i.e. *on earth* and even *within our solar system* (mostly). It is only today that we are actually able to measure precisely enough to show relativistic effects in "common" cases.

Hence, Newton's mechanics were (and still are!) used in applications where the margin of error due to their not reflecting reality is so small that it does not matter for the practical considerations in question.