# Why is modern physics still connected to Western notions of time?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, physics

as Rasheedah Phillips says “**Afrofuturism uses a completely different construct of time and engages a different notion of time consciousness and notion of the future than does the European brand of futurism, which is based on linear constructs of time and progress, and remnants of Newtonian physics updated with some Einstein relativity”"**

In her book "Black Quantum Futurism" Rasheedah argues that

"that quantum mechanical interpretations of time, spacetime, causality, and interactions are more in agreement with Afrocentric understandings of these same phenomena than with Western ones" that quantum mechanical interpretations of time, spacetime, causality, and interactions are more in agreement with Afrocentric understandings of these same phenomena than with Western ones,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Quantum_Futurism

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better fit for the physics stack, than philosophy?

Comment: its more of a philosophical question

Comment: Wouldn't someone with expertise in physics be able to better speak about why physics uses a certain concept of time, than a philosopher? The answer is likely that the concept of time that physics uses is empirically testable against reality. The formulas they use with time as a component are testable, and repeatable

Comment: Isn't the answer obvious? Every single physicist has been a white male. Obviously white males are going to adopt their white time and not the Afrotime that Black Men would use instead. It's why Africa is going to be physics capital of the world while white males will just keep using their out-dated white time they got from Newton and Einstein (also white males).

Comment: This is better suited to literature.SE.

Comment: What does it mean "modern physicis" ? Einstein's physics is modern (and Western) and Quantun Mech is modern (and Western) and they are "connected" to different concepts of time.

Comment: Why indeed. It may be because physicists pay so little attention to philosophy. But I'm, not sure it;s possible to generalise about physicists views of time given their variety.

Comment: Is this question "Given that a book was published 2 years ago with a different way of thinking, why hasn't the entire philosophical/scientific/engineering community all moved to this new way of thinking?"

Comment: For those of us who are unfamiliar with this "afrofuture" understanding of space and time, can you provide any insight into what it is?  As far as I can tell the only position here is that an author claims their way is better.

Comment: Related (but not duplicate) https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/56070/why-did-scientists-still-follow-newtons-scientific-framework-even-though-kant?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Afrofuturism is a specific movement in both the visual and literary arts. The conceptual thinking that goes onto it uses physics as a departure point but it's not physics per se. The same thing goes for science-fiction from HG Wells to Stars Wars and beyond.

It has nothing to do with the philosophy of physics, philosophy or indeed with physics. You're better asking this question on Literature.SE.

Comment: yes I know that it's mostly an artistic movement, but her main argument is that modern physics has been using western notions of linear time as a foundation

Answer (score 0):

Physics works with time the way it does because nobody's demonstrated anything better, fundamentally.  If some physicist takes another idea of time and shows that it's better in some respect than what we're using now. it will be considered.  It would be necessary to define the new idea of time precisely enough to make predictions that are definitely different somewhere from what we've got now.

This isn't a deep philosophical issue to a physicist.  It's a matter of empiricism.  Does this theory make better predictions in some limited field than the current one?